# call url on azure app service with authentication and authorization from Webjobs (or better way)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-6.0, azure-webjobs

net 6 web app running on app service, with authentication over AAD + app roles on app registration, i need something that will call me specific action on that app service every 2hours for example

```
//action on web app
[Authorize(Roles = "Root")]
public IActionResult NeedToCallThis()
{
    //code
    return View();
}
```

when i create console app for WebJobs that will just try to call
....azurewebsites.net/Controller/NeedToCallThis
it will ofc return auth website from microsoft, even if i run in on AppService WebJobs
so i need some kind of authentication or if someone use powershell or something?

```
//console app for webjob
using System.Net;
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString("https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/cont/act");
Console.WriteLine(content);
```

More info:
when i run webjob i will get this in logs of webjob:
[image]
same login page of microsoft will returns me powershell script that calls web application

your answears are not bad but i dont have problem with setting schedule on webjobs, that is fine but when i run the webjob that should trigger me web application i need some kind of authentication or i dont know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run triggered Azure WebJob from Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346062/run-triggered-azure-webjob-from-code)

Comment: Have you tried to set the permissions in the "access control (IAM)" menu in the azure interface? (e.g. contributor)
In the webapp under the webjobs menu, if you click on the right webjob, you should have a username and password, you can authenticate with that.
I think the linked question might help with authentication.

Comment: I don't have a problem with calling the webjob, I need to call the web application url from the webjob (https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/controller/action)
but when i call the webapp url it returns me the microsoft login page

Comment: That's right, because you have to authenticate yourself. You can authenticate yourself with the username + password that the webjob provides when you open a webjob on the azure portal. This way you can automate your webjob calls.
The other option is to authenticate via the microsoft login page, but then the call will clearly not be automated.

Comment: i will try it with some kind of silent auth

Comment: @ZdenekBarta - Are you still looking for the sol ?