# WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

My Azure continuous webjob stopped giving reason "WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down"

Logs from Kudu log

```
[12/09/2016 17:11:49 > 2e7853: WARN] Reached maximum allowed output lines for this run, to see all of the job's logs you can enable website application diagnostics
[12/09/2016 17:12:42 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
[12/09/2016 17:12:42 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[12/09/2016 17:12:47 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[12/09/2016 17:12:47 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[12/09/2016 17:12:55 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[12/09/2016 17:12:55 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] WebJob singleton setting is False
[12/09/2016 17:12:57 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] Run script 'VimsProcessHistoryData.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[12/09/2016 17:12:57 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
```

It already Always On.

Can some one help to resolve this

Comment: It seems that you deployed at this period. Is that right?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the site name here or indirectly (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)?

Comment: Because your job runs inside your webapp, when you webapp shuts down restarts, your job will do the same. You need to investigate why your webapp has stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my job to continuous web job.. and It worked.

It tried couple of options with triggered webjob like keep it Always On.. but that didn't work.

I enable diagnostic logging n all .. but it didn't give me any clue.

When checked with Microsoft support they responded that the VM is moved mistakenly so it cause job to stop.

Answer (score 1):

> [12/09/2016 17:12:42 > 2e7853: SYS INFO] WebJob is stopping due to website shutting down
>
> [12/09/2016 **17:12:42** > 2e7853: SYS INFO] Status changed to **Stopping**
>
> [12/09/2016 **17:12:55** > 2e7853: SYS INFO] Status changed to **Starting**

As I known, if something causes your web app to restart, then your WebJob would quickly restart as long as your web app restarts. If this happens frequently, I assumed that you need to [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) for your web app and check the Process Explorer in the SCM. If this hanppens infrequently, you could try to re-deply your WebJob. Also you could deploy your WebJob to a new empty web app for isolating this issue. Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502696/continuous-webjob-stops-automatically), you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. it tried few of these options