# Kudu on permise - webjob continuous stopped every 15 minutes

Tags: iis, kudu

I use Kudu localy on my server and i host Webjobs with queue trigger. I see that every 15 minutes, Webjobs stopped.

I see that on Azure you have Always On option and i try to add on Kudu Web.config file this option but it doesn't work:

I also set the Application pool of my IIS kudu service web site on AlwaysRunning but no impact.

I then create a script that ping Kudu Api Webjob page every minute in order to keep the web site alive but still no effect.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502696/continuous-webjob-stops-automatically

Comment: Many thanks for your help. In this post, it looks like the Always On option is the issue and it cannot be selected in a free mode. In my case, i am on premise so i don't have this option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update the Idle Timeout in IIS Application Pool to 0 and it remove the 20 min timeout.